# What can a non-mathematician do if he discovers something ground breaking?

Tags: publishing

This is more of a curiosity that I've been asking myself lately, and I thought to ask it here. So, what can someone there's not a mathematician do, if he has discovered something ground breaking.
I assume, that he wouldn't be taken seriously by the mathematical community, if he found a way to publish his discoveries.

Comment: If it's published in a decent math journal then it would certainly be taken seriously.  And if it's truly a ground breaking discovery, one could probably just write a paper about it and submit it to a journal and it would be accepted.

Comment: "Something ground breaking" in mathematics? How would they know it is ground breaking if they are not a mathematician?

Comment: learn enough math to at least display it correctly. oh and peer review ...